# Java ArrayList addAll only adding 1 element?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I basically put some `Integer` objects in an `ArrayList x`, then put some in an `ArrayList y`, then did `y.addAll(x)`, but it seems to be only adding the first one and leaving out all the rest! Isn't it supposed to add ALL? I looked it up on Oracle and they showed what seemed to be the EXACT SAME EXAMPLE yet mine is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
Integer c = 3;
x.add(a);
x.add(b);
ArrayList< Integer> y = new ArrayList< Integer>();
y.addAll(x);
```

yet `y` seems to only have `1` in it and missing the `2` and the `3`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Yes, sorry, I know I didn't actually add c to x yet, but even when I do, and then print y, I still get [1] instead of [1,2,3]. This is what I don't understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SumArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer a = 1;
        Integer b = 2;
        Integer c = 3;
        x.add(a);
        x.add(b);
        System.out.println(x);
        //System.out.println(calculateSumArrayListHelper(x));

        ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        y.addAll(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        //System.out.println(calculateSumArrayListHelper(y));
    }
}
```

Here is a pic of what I see:
http://postimg.org/image/ms0y68nnh/

Comment: [No repro here using your code](https://ideone.com/hfz2zt)

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to print all elements ?

Comment: I'm sure you get [1,2] not just 3 because you haven't added it

Comment: How do you know it only contains one element ?

Comment: Okay, here I'll just give you my entire code, and yeah I realize I didn't add 3, but it's still printing just [1] when I print y and [1,2] when i print x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the picture you have posted it is clear. You are calling `calculateSumArrayListHelper(x)` before the `addAll()`. Inside that method you remove elements from the given list. So at the time you call `y.addAll(x)`, elements have been removed from `x`.

Comment: Oh my goodddddddd............................ I'm such a idiot. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In your code after executing `y.addAll(x);` y will contain only 2 elements `[1,2]`. you never add `c` to `x`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
Integer c = 3;
x.add(a);
x.add(b);
x.add(c); // add c to x
ArrayList< Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
y.addAll(x);
System.out.println("size = " + y.size());
```

Will produce :

> size = 3

And y will contain :

> [1,2,3]

You are **removing** item from `x` in your method `calculateSumArrayListHelper()`. That's why you don't have the expected result.

Comment all calls to this method and check the content of `y`... It should be right.

Comment: Yeah this is what I don't understand. I literally have done this exactly, but when I print y, it just gives me "[1]" and not "[1,2,3]"

Comment: And printing `y.size()` what is the result?

Comment: when I print y.size() it says 1

Answer (score 0):

Just put sop on last line.

```
System.out.println(y);
```

So that you can see the result.which is coming [1, 2] in my system.
You are not getting 3 as because you never add it in X.

```
x.add(a);
x.add(b);
x.add(c);
```